# generate schema from stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to make a schema diagram from an SQL Server database using the stored procedures of this database?

I don't mind if I must use an external software.

Comment: Can you only see the stored procedures in the database? Not table?

Comment: @gbn: @Filip De Vos: I have full visibility on everything. The problem is that the database hasn't got any schema. it is only tables, views and stored procedures. there are no FKs. joins are done only by queries. I don't want them to be storeded in the database. Just to view them visualy. ie by an external tool. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try playing around with [CodeSmith Generator](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator#overview). It's **SchemaExplorer Schema Discovery API** allows you to programmatically access database elements for a given database and do something creative with it. However, it will still be logically hard to reverse-engineer a schema/diagram this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a SQLCLR procedure which uses the [Scripter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153.aspx) from the SMO library.

**update**: more info on the question reveals the idea is to generate a table schema with dependencies based on the content of the stored procedures.

The approach would be to generate the table structure from the information_schema views and then parse the contents of the `syscomments` table to figure out the relations. This will always be approximate as it is very hard to establish the one-to-many relationships purely from the SQL Statements. I think you can make a guess based on the field which is referenced more.

Comment: Permissions will still apply = no table visibility. And if OP could create stored procs then probably they would generate it from the tables they could see too.

Comment: I don't see where he mentions an issue around viewing tables?

Comment: @Filip De Vos: You have assumed "how I can generate schema using *a* stored procedure". OP says "..using the* stored procedures". As a native English speaker I read this as "how do I get my table schema from the stored procedures that I can see"

Comment: @gbn: @Filip De Vos: I have full visibility on everything. The problem is that the database hasn't got any schema. it is only tables, views and stored procedures. there are no FKs. joins are done only by queries. I don't want them to be storeded in the database. Just to view them visualy. ie by an external tool. Thanks

Comment: @Filip De Vos: "After Update" Yes, this is something that could accomplish the task, but I was hoping for something easier :) Thanks anyway. I will not mark this as answered yet in case someone else has any better idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see the tables then you can not generate the schema.

That is, you can't if you have permissions on stored procedures only.

At least two reasons:

- the stored proc may JOIN and use several tables
- you can't see constraints, indexes, keys etc even if you had table names

Basically, you can only:

- see what you have permissions on in SSMS etc
- see the internals if you have VEIW DEFINITION rights

Edit, after clarification

There is no way to script *implied* aspects (such as missing foreign keys) of the schema from code